# JSON select name and value

Tags: r

Select the name and value from a JSON file with R.

I have the following JSON file:

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Los Angeles Kings",
                    "Golden State Warriros",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "11",
                    "12",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "12"
            },
            "q2": {
                "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ],
                "answer": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I import the JSON file:

```
result <- fromJSON( "C:\\Users\\julen.peral\\Desktop\\json_files\\data\\example_2.json")
```

and the I want to select the values. 
For example:
"question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?"

I would use the following code:

```
result[[1]]
```

and I will get: "Which one is correct team name in NBA?".

My question is how to get "question".

The final idea is to do a loop to scan all the names and values and save as I want in a data frame. I know that there are some packages but I want to know how to do it myself because I have some json

See the code to scan the values (I would like the same for the names) I

```
for(a in 1:length(result)) {
  for (b in 1:length(result[[a]])){
    for (c in 1:length(result[[a]][[b]])){
      for (d in 1:length(result[[a]][[b]][[c]])){
        for (e in 1:length(result[[a]][[b]][[c]][[d]])){
          for (f in 1:length(result[[a]][[b]][[c]][[d]][[e]])){

            print(result[[a]][[b]][[c]][[d]][[e]][[f]])
}}}}}}
```

If I run the previous code I see the following values:

```
[1] "Which one is correct team name in NBA?"
[1] "New York Bulls"
[1] "Los Angeles Kings"
[1] "Golden State Warriros"
[1] "Huston Rocket"
[1] "Huston Rocket"
[1] "5 + 7 = ?"
[1] "10"
[1] "11"
[1] "12"
[1] "13"
[1] "12"
[1] "12 - 8 = ?"
[1] "1"
[1] "2"
[1] "3"
[1] "4"
[1] "4"
```

But I don't know in this case which is question or answer.

Thank you for your time

Julen

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal solution, but I think it greatly simplifies things for you:

```r
j <- jsonlite::fromJSON(file("~/StackOverflow/Julen.json"))
str(j)
# List of 1
#  $ quiz:List of 2
#   ..$ sport:List of 1
#   .. ..$ q1:List of 3
#   .. .. ..$ question: chr "Which one is correct team name in NBA?"
#   .. .. ..$ options : chr [1:4] "New York Bulls" "Los Angeles Kings" "Golden State Warriros" "Huston Rocket"
#   .. .. ..$ answer  : chr "Huston Rocket"
#   ..$ maths:List of 2
#   .. ..$ q1:List of 3
#   .. .. ..$ question: chr "5 + 7 = ?"
#   .. .. ..$ options : chr [1:4] "10" "11" "12" "13"
#   .. .. ..$ answer  : chr "12"
#   .. ..$ q2:List of 3
#   .. .. ..$ question: chr "12 - 8 = ?"
#   .. .. ..$ options : chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
#   .. .. ..$ answer  : chr "4"
```

Here's a "tidy" way of processing it:

```r
purrr::flatten_dfc(j) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(.) %>%
  as.list(.)
# $q1
# [1] "Which one is correct team name in NBA?"
# [2] "New York Bulls"                        
# [3] "Los Angeles Kings"                     
# [4] "Golden State Warriros"                 
# [5] "Huston Rocket"                         
# [6] "Huston Rocket"                         
# $q11
# [1] "5 + 7 = ?" "10"        "11"        "12"        "13"        "12"       
# $q2
# [1] "12 - 8 = ?" "1"          "2"          "3"          "4"         
# [6] "4"
```

Unfortunately, you lose the actual question name, as the second `q1` becomes `q11`. And all parts are in one vector: the question is the first in the `character` vector, answer is the last, and options are everything in between.

(There is likely a more-direct way of doing this.)

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to convert it to a tbl_df and extract all the info

```
library(tidyversse)
modify_depth(result, 2, ~ 
    map_df(.x, ~ as_tibble(.x), .id = 'q_no') )  %>%
   pluck(1) %>% 
   map_df(~ .x, .id = "categ")
# A tibble: 12 x 5
#   categ q_no  question                               options               answer       
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>                                  <chr>                 <chr>        
# 1 sport q1    Which one is correct team name in NBA? New York Bulls        Huston Rocket
# 2 sport q1    Which one is correct team name in NBA? Los Angeles Kings     Huston Rocket
# 3 sport q1    Which one is correct team name in NBA? Golden State Warriros Huston Rocket
# 4 sport q1    Which one is correct team name in NBA? Huston Rocket         Huston Rocket
# 5 maths q1    5 + 7 = ?                              10                    12           
# 6 maths q1    5 + 7 = ?                              11                    12           
# 7 maths q1    5 + 7 = ?                              12                    12           
# 8 maths q1    5 + 7 = ?                              13                    12           
# 9 maths q2    12 - 8 = ?                             1                     4            
#10 maths q2    12 - 8 = ?                             2                     4            
#11 maths q2    12 - 8 = ?                             3                     4            
#12 maths q2    12 - 8 = ?                             4                     4
```

#### data

```
result <-  jsonlite::fromJSON("example_2.json")
```